# Rounding low values (e.g. 0.000005) to zero using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export

I'm trying to export via ui.Chart a time series of NO2 form multiple points, but at the moment of printing the chart and then exporting that to .csv, the values are rounded to 0 even though they do have value but are quiet low, for example: 0.0000000052 mol/m2.

Is there any way to put them in scientific notation or that at the moment of export, the decimals do not get rounded?

Here's the code:

```
var data = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD19A2_GRANULES') // Colección de datos.
              .select('Optical_Depth_047') // Banda de interés.
              .filterBounds(est); // Capa de estaciones.
var startDate = ee.Date('2020-01-01'); // Fecha de inicio.
var endDate = ee.Date('2021-01-01'); // Fecha final.
                                    /* Se recomienda descargar los datos hasta 10 años cuando 
                                    la resolución espacial es mensual, y sólo un ño cuando la 
                                    resolución espacial es diaria, dado que sólo exporta 500 
                                    elementos como máximo. Además, tanto para una resolución 
                                    espacial mensual como diaria se debe considerar un día más 
                                    a la fecha final, pues contabiliza los datos desde el "0" 
                                    (cero). 
                                    */

var days = endDate.difference(startDate, 'days'); /* Se indica 'days' cuando se trate de datos 
                                                  diarios, y 'month' para datos mensuales. Cam-
                                                  biar esta opción en las líneas que se requie-
                                                  ran.
                                                  */
var daysStep = 1;
var timeSeries = ee.ImageCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(0, days.subtract(1), daysStep)
    .map(function (offsetDays) {
      var start = startDate.advance(offsetDays, 'days');
      var end = start.advance(daysStep, 'days');
      var composite = data
        .filterDate(start, end)
        .median(); /* Elegir de acuerdo al parámetro estadístico que se necesite, esto es, Media
                  "mean()", Máximo "max()", Mínimo "min()", Mediana "median()", etc. 
                  */
      return composite
        .set('system:time_start', start.millis())
        .set('empty', composite.bandNames().size().eq(0));
    })
  ).filterMetadata('empty', 'equals', 0);

print(timeSeries.size());
print(timeSeries);

var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection: timeSeries, 
  regions: est, 
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
  band: 'Optical_Depth_047' , // Banda de interés.
  scale: 1000, 
  });

print(chart);
Map.addLayer(est);
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work because the object `est` is not provided. This post might help with your issue: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/358283/is-it-possible-to-round-decimal-places-for-float-data-in-google-earth-engine

Comment: I'm sorry @JohnPolo. [link] (https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/romeldrivera/est) Here's the layer with the stations.